# What's a "worker", or a "worker name"

Tags: mining, mining-pools

Using a "worker" or "worker name" is often an option when you do pool mining. It is often exemplified by "rig1". But how do you create one, and what is its use?

Answer (score 10):

In pool mining context a `worker` is simply a machine that mines the blockchain.

#### A `rig`

> A mining rig is a computer system used for mining bitcoins. The rig might be a dedicated miner where it was procured, built and operated specifically for mining or it could otherwise be a computer that fills other needs, such as performing as a gaming system, and is used to mine only on a part-time basis. [wiki](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Mining_rig)

#### The `rig1`

Its a name to identify your machines when you connect it to a pool with a miner address. You can use the same mining address on different `rig`s and identify them with `rig` name, some pools show the rig name on the status page.

Answer (score 0):

The pool I mine on reflects activity for "miners" and, as a subset, workers. I have yet to figure out how to designate the individual devices (gpus) as workers.

Answer (score 0):

Its ecosystem and computer mining system in pool mining context a worker is simply a machine that mines the blockchain.